# Trouble setting up kuma on vagrant for development

Tags: mysql

After a lot of fuss and research, I finally found a project I would be interested in to contribute to. I need help with this **one last step**. In [this document](https://github.com/mozilla/kuma/blob/master/docs/installation-vagrant.rst), in the section "creating an admin user" I signed in with persona and ran `mysql -uroot kuma`and followed instructions as specified. I got this

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

for mysql update command instead of

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

as mentioned in the document. All the previous steps are successfully done and I am able to get the webpage locally up without any issues. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Got passed the error. I had to run server locally and then sign up with persona on my local page. I was foolishly doing it on mozilla browser.